# Spring Boot Config Server Using GitHub Repository and SSH Login

Tags: git, spring-boot, ssh

I have been trying to set up a Config Server, in Spring Boot for which configuration will be served from a private Github repository. Earlier, the configuration with user name and password used to work well for the same.

Like in my application.properties file, I Could simple provide the details as follows:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          username: trolley
          password: strongpassword
```

But using the same configuration, I got an email from GitHub saying that username and password-based authentication is deprecated.
You can look at this link for more details on that.  [Token authentication requirements for Git operations](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)

So, I proceeded with SSH-based authentication. I followed the GitHub Tutorial to create a public-private key pair and successfully added that to my git repository. Here is the link to that [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

After this, I tried my SSH Connection using my private key and got a successful response.

```
Hi ankur19030! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

So, that implies, my GitHub connection setup with Public and private keys is complete. All that is left now is to configure the spring boot properties, in application.yml file in spring boot
Here is my configuration for the same:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com:ankur19030/cosylab_config.git
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          privateKey: |
                         -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
                         MY SSH PRIVATE KEY
                         -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now, I am getting the following error in spring boot:

```
  Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:

    Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I don't understand, why the private key is showing as invalid, when I have successfully tested the ssh connection on terminal using the same key.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [this tutorial](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.0.M6/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties), the private key format might be an old PEM one, not an OPENSSH one.

Try and regenerate a key to the old formet, to see if it works:

```
ssh-keygen -P "" -m PEM -t rsa -f secondKey
```

Copy the content of `secondKey` (after testing it first with `ssh -Tv -i secondKey git@github.com`)

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_authentication) contains opposite information to the answer above:
It states:

> Warning: When working with SSH keys, the expected ssh private-key must begin with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. If the key starts with -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- then the RSA key will not load when spring-cloud-config server is started. The error looks like:

```
- Error in object 'spring.cloud.config.server.git': codes [PrivateKeyIsValid.spring.cloud.config.server.git,PrivateKeyIsValid]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.cloud.config.server.git.,]; arguments []; default message []]; default message [Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key]
```

The documented example for generating an RSA key that should work is:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/config_server_deploy_key.rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I migrated from Spring Cloud **Hoxton.SR6/Java 11** to Spring Cloud **2021.0.8/Java 17**, I wasn't able to authenticate to Bitbucket through the same PEM private key that used to work before, I would get the following error with no visible indication that the private key in ***spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key*** was incorrect:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git@xxxxx:7999/test/test.git: Cannot log in at bitbucket.com:7999
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available
```

I tried converting the old PEM format private key to the new OpenSSH PEM format but it didn't work.

What I had to do was to recreate a new private key and publish its corresponding public key to Bitbucket again. That was the only way i made it work. This is the command I used to recreate the key:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "any_email@any_domain.com"
```